# javascript - keep track of successful ajax requests / returns

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to find a way to keep track of successful ajax returns using javascript only not jquery or other libs.  What I want to do is to show a loading graphic when the function is fired and clear the graphic when all the results are returned.  My function breaks up the input and calls a defined number of ajax requests.

I read that there is no straight forward way to do it.  I am trying to set up a function to count the successful requests, but I am running into a logical barrier that I can't solve. My basic outline is below:

TIA

Edited to update solution.

The solution is to create ct as a global variable
My working code outline is

```
var ct = 0;//declare outside of function as global


function ajaxcallback(...) { 
...
if (success)
{
//output/do something
ct++; //increase global ct by 1

countajax (total);//call countajax

}
}//end function

function countajax (total)
{
    if (ct == total)
    {
    //turn off loading graphic  
    }
}//end countajax
```

I suppose the function countajax is not necessary, the comparison of ct == total can be done without calling the function countajax.

Comment: You're missing a 2nd `=` in your `if` block.

Comment: Thanks Adam, but that wont solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually a very straightforward way to do this:

Call a method from inside every ajax callback, and make sure that this function only actually does anything if all the ajax calls are completed, like this:

```
(function() {
    var ajax1_done = ajax2_done = ajax3_done = false;

    function ajax1_callback() {
      ajax1_done = true;
      run_when_all_is_done();
    }

    function ajax2_callback() {
      ajax2_done = true;
      run_when_all_is_done();
    }

    function ajax3_callback() {
      ajax3_done = true;
      run_when_all_is_done();
    }

    function run_when_all_is_done() {
      if(ajax1_done && ajax2_done && ajax3_done) {
        //do stuff here
      }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, I think this is great, but I will need to generate the number of "ajax_done" variables dynamically.  Your solution and Brians solution keyed me into having to declare a global variable, which I was hesitant to do, but it works. I will share the solution once it is tested.

Comment: You don't need a global variable - use a closure. Look at my updated answer to see how. The immediate function that wraps the code acts as a local scope for the variables declared inside it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to keep a variable that tracks how many requests you made and another that tracks how many responses you've received. Then after you've kicked off all of your ajax calls start a poller (setInterval) that checks for the response count variable to match the total requests variable.

```
var totalRequests = 0,
    successfulRequests = 0,
    poller = null;

// psuedo code
totalRequests++;
ajax("http://server.com", function(resp){ successfulRequests++; } /** callback */);

totalRequests++;
ajax("http://server.com", function(resp){ successfulRequests++; } /** callback */);

totalRequests++;
ajax("http://server.com", function(resp){ successfulRequests++; } /** callback */);

// run poller after you've kicked off all your ajax requests
poller = window.setInterval(function(){
  if(totalRequests === successfulRequests){
    alert("all ajax finished");
    window.clearInterval(poller);
    poller = null;
  }
},100);
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, I am will try the method and hope it applies to my situation.